# How to still play audio between HTML files

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html5-audio

I'm trying to figure out how to use `audio` to listen songs between files.
For example, if i'm listening to some music in http://localhost/mysite/index.html, I want to still listen to that song when I move to http://localhost/mysite/people.html.
I had the thought of using `iframe` to jump from file to file and have the  tag outside, but I don't know if that will cause performance issues.

Comment: An `iframe` would work. There wouldn't be any performance issues, however frames are a very old and outdated method. The modern way to do this would be to make your site use a Single Page Architecture, or [SPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application). That way there is no page transition. Every new request for data is made using AJAX, so there is no interruption to the audio which is playing.

Comment: Another important question is how often will this person be switching between pages?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I'm new to SPA but it seems really good and the way to go, may I have some tutorial? Can't see any proper one on YouTube. Thanks for the quick reply!

Comment: @Wayne I'm working on a social media project so it would be some kind of Twitter, the user would pretty much move around in every moment and I want to use the music as a background between pages

Comment: This is probably out of my league then I don't have much expierience with audio. I wonder if you can get the audio to play on the window object instead of a specific page.